# Is it possible to Merge or Branch between different TFS servers?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

I want to branch my solutions to a different TFS server with TFS 2010.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot branch between servers (or Project Collections) in TFS.

Do you need to do a one off move to a new server? In that case, restoring a backup of your current server to the new server and deleting the Team Projects you don't need might be a solution. If you need to be able to "merge" the code back to the original server at some point you could look at the [TFS Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe). This will allow you to move the code over to a new server and also keep the code synchronised.

However there are limitations with the toolkit, see the link for more information.

Why do you need to use a new server? Why won't a new branch in the current Team Project suffice?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to change the server that my teams use. It is enough for me to move whole projects in one tfs to another. So backup and restore are enough as you say